# Can I "replay" a replay in Starcraft 2?

Tags: starcraft-2

**Can I "replay" a multiplayer replay in Starcraft 2?**

And by "replay" I mean the ability to interfere with the replay at any given point. Thus allowing to answer questions we all have when watching a replay: *I wonder what would actually happen if I had done this instead of that?*

Comment: It would be an interesting feature if it existed.

Comment: I hoped that maybe the map editor would at least allow this somehow. Like opening a replay in the editor and saving a particular time in the replay as starting point for a new map....

Comment: I have never tried opening a replay in the map editor. I don't know if it is even possible to do so.

Comment: Downvoters: why?

Comment: +1 for your comment. It would actually be a great feature. But I don't know if this is the right place.

Comment: Just found [SALT](http://www.teamliquid.net/forum/viewmessage.php?topic_id=306069), which seem to be basically custom multiplayer maps for SC2 that allow saving and restoring. Comes close to that I want. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a tool that was announced on TeamLiquid.net which allows resuming from replays. However, this program does directly interface with SC2 - which is not allowed and might get recognized as hack - and might get you banned.

Check this TL.net thread for more info:
http://www.teamliquid.net/forum/viewmessage.php?topic_id=328785

Also, there are specific maps which allow saving and loading game states which you and a friend can use to test battles and such. Search the custom games for SALT (save and load tool) maps.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no way to control units inside of a replay. You can only see what has happened and slow down and speed up the time.

Comment: The downvote on this answer was for what again?

Comment: There are tools available to perform the OP's requested action.

Comment: Not that come standard in the game.

Answer (score 0):

No. Replays are basically recordings of the actions each player took within a match. You can watch from various viewpoints and change the flow of time, but you can't change the events that unfold.

The "what if…" question you ask is pretty difficult to accurately answer. If you had performed different actions in the match, your opponent may have reacted differently. For replays of multi-player matches that can't happen since you and your opponent are no longer connected. I suppose computer AIs could take over for the missing players - but then you're not really playing the same match.